# Code adds extra linebreak when loaded or saved

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, joomla

This is the wrong code (screenshot from chrome console)
[image]

This is how it should be
[image]

I´m not sure if it´s the code that loads it from the db, which is:

```
<p><?php echo nl2br($row[$x]['body']);?></p>
```

Or the code saving the text:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "index.php",
                data: { option: "com_ajax", module: "usernotes" , method: "edit", format: "json" , Id: edit_id, body: curBody.replace("", /(\r\n|\n)/g) }
```

The function the above ajax calls inserts it to SQL as follows:

```
$db->quoteName('body') . ' = ' . $db->quote(nl2br($bodyToUpdate))
```

I thought i could be some returns from jQuery. Thats why I´ve tried:

```
curBody.replace("", /(\r\n|\n)/g)
```

Comment: It can be about encoding. You should consider utf-8 with boom.

Comment: `nl2br` *inserts* a `<br>` before new line characters, it doesn't replace them. That's why your text node starts with a new line.

Comment: @DarthJDG  I think you are right. but without nl2br i get no line breaks. But in the console, I can see that there is line breaks.

Comment: @DarthJDG Arhh, works now!... The solution was to remove `nl2br` and in the css add `white-space:` pre; for the `<p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove `nl2br`.

Code was:

```
$db->quoteName('body') . ' = ' . $db->quote(nl2br($bodyToUpdate))
```

Should be:

```
$db->quoteName('body') . ' = ' . $db->quote($bodyToUpdate)
```

and in the css add `white-space: pre;` for the `<p>` Like:

```
.usernotetext p {
    white-space: pre;
}
```